"Correct" approach to pass response from GoogleDriveAPI files.get(alt: media) to react frontend through express backend
I am querying (successfully) the google drive api using this function in my nodejs express backend:
export async function getImageById(imageId: string, fields?: string) {
  try {
    await (await drive()).files.get({
      supportsAllDrives: true,
      fileId: imageId,
      alt: 'media',
      fields: fields || '*'
    }, { responseType: "arraybuffer" })
    .then((res) => {
      console.log('Image:', res.data);
      return res;
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error('Error getting image:', err);
    return null;
  }
}

based on this stackoverflow post where two different patterns (arraybuffer and stream) are explained. I then offer it as an API endpoint in the following way:
router.get('/drive/image/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        res.send(await getImageById(req.params.id));
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error:', error);
        res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal Server Error' });
        }
});

The goal I am trying to achieve is querying a drive for an image's data, receiving that data, and then displaying it in my frontend. On the frontend side, I will be querying the backend, receiving either a stream or arraybuffer (I think), and in the case of the array buffer, using something like:
src={`data:image/jpeg;base64,${Buffer.from(<Array Buffer from Backend>).toString('base64')}`}


However, I am having problems with the data as its being passed. After making the request to the google api, I get a sizable array buffer back, as I would expect, but then when I view it on the frontend with the following function:
const fetchImage = async (fileId: string) => {
    await axios.get(`${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_API_BASE_URL}/api/drive/image/${fileId}`, { responseType: 'arraybuffer' })
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        setImage(response.data)})
      .catch((error) => console.error('Error fetching folder contents:', error));
  };

I see an empty array buffer. My question boils down to:

What is the correct/best way to just pass data from the backend to the frontend, I guess in the most efficient way possible in a sense that it just hands it over without doing anything else.
Where am I going wrong on this passing so that I receive an empty array buffer.
Is an array buffer the best approach? Would stream be better? I originally tried querying the api without specifying the response type and converting that into a blob, but ran into type errors as the response is a schema$file

